# Inverse involving polynomial and trigonometric understanding

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

Given $f(x) = x^3+ 3\sin x + 2\cos x$ and $a = 2$

What is $({f^-}^1)'(a)$?

This is my understanding, I'm figuring out how to continue:

let $y=({f^-}^1)(x)$

$$f(y)=x$$

$$f'(y) \frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{f'({f^-}^1)(x)}$$

$$({f^-}^1)'(a) = \frac{1}{f'({f^-}^1)(a)}$$

$$f(x) = x^3 +3\sin x + 2\cos x$$

let $a = f(x)$ => $x={f^-}^1(a)$

$$x^3 +3\sin x + 2\cos x-2=0$$

Let me know if I'm heading in the right direction. I used the same method to solve the same type of question but in polynomial form only.

Comment: can I check if $a=2$ or $a=4$?

Comment: The first has obviously its root at $x=0$, the second somewhere around $0.7775618175915284$.

Comment: oops sorry, a = 2 @SiongThyeGoh